# One Page, Two Modals (two different actions)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page with two buttons which call two modals.

Each modal have a SUBMIT button and I'm like to perform different actions.

My problem is, when I open second modal and try to submit form, first modal show warning of required fields.

How to perform actions separately? in this case OR send Add contact form OR send Add Document form?

Thanks all.

Button 1 ADD CONTACT:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#add_contact"><i class="icon-user-plus"></i> <? echo $msg['new']; ?> <? echo $msg['contact']; ?></a>
```

BUTTON 2 ADD DOCUMENT

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#add_document"><i class="icon-user-plus"></i> <? echo $msg['new']; ?> <? echo $msg['document']; ?></a>
```

1ST modal Add CONTACT

```
<!-- Add Contact MODAL -->
        <div id="add_contact" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h5 class="modal-title"><? echo $msg['add_contact']; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <form method="post" id="message_add" class="form-validate-jquery" action="suppliers_inc.sql.php">
                        
                        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="add_contact" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="supplier_id" value="<? echo $supplier_id ?>" />
                        
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['contact_type']; ?> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <select name="contact_type_id" class="select-search" required="required" data-placeholder="">
                                        <?php
                                            $query_contact_type = "SELECT DISTINCT type_id, type_description FROM supplier_contacts_type ORDER BY type_description";
                                            $result_contact_type = $mysqli->query($query_contact_type);
                                            while ($row_contact_type = $result_contact_type->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                echo "<option></option>";
                                                echo "<option value=\"{$row_contact_type['type_id']}\">";
                                                echo $row_contact_type['type_description'];
                                                echo "</option>";
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['position']; ?> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_position" required="required" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['name']; ?> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_name" required="required" class="form-control">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['surname']; ?> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_surname" required="required" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['telephone']; ?> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_telephone" placeholder="Telefone FIXO" data-mask="99 9999-9999" required="required" class="form-control">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['int']; ?></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_int" class="form-control">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['hours']; ?></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_hours" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['mobile']; ?></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_mobile" placeholder="Celular" data-mask="99 9-9999-9999" class="form-control">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['email']; ?></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_email" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['date_of_birth']; ?></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_date_of_birth" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" data-mask="99/99/9999" class="form-control">
                                    </div>                                      
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="contact_default" class="control-primary">
                                                <? echo $msg['default_contact']; ?>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                        
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal"><? echo $msg['close']; ?></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><? echo $msg['save']; ?> <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Add Contact MODAL -->
```

2ND modal Add DOCUMENT

```
            <!-- Add Document MODAL -->
        <div id="add_document" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h5 class="modal-title"><? echo $msg['add_document']; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <form method="post" id="document_add" class="form-validate-jquery" action="suppliers_inc.sql.php">
                        
                        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="add_document" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="supplier_id" value="<? echo $supplier_id ?>" />
                        
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['document_classification']; ?> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <select name="classification_id" class="select-search" required="required" data-placeholder="">
                                        <?php
                                            $query_document_classification = "SELECT DISTINCT classification_id, classification_description FROM supplier_documents_classification ORDER BY classification_description";
                                            $result_document_classification = $mysqli->query($query_document_classification);
                                            while ($row_document_classification = $result_document_classification->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                echo "<option></option>";
                                                echo "<option value=\"{$row_document_classification['classification_id']}\">";
                                                echo $row_document_classification['classification_description'];
                                                echo "</option>";
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['description']; ?> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="document_description" required="required" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['issue_date']; ?></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_date_of_birth" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" data-mask="99/99/9999" class="form-control">
                                    </div>  

                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label><? echo $msg['expiry_date']; ?></label>
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_date_of_birth" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" data-mask="99/99/9999" class="form-control">
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="contact_default" class="control-primary">
                                                <? echo $msg['expiry_notification']; ?>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="contact_default" class="control-primary">
                                                <? echo $msg['lock_supplier']; ?>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal"><? echo $msg['close']; ?></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><? echo $msg['save']; ?> <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Add Document MODAL -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must be in your javascript/jquery form submit handler function

```
$('form#message_add').on('submit',function(){
   //do something
});

$('form#document_add').on('submit',function(){
   //do something
});
```